# Changing Word Icon in Top Left of FileDialog

Tags: vba, excel, icons, ms-word

Is there a way to change the Microsoft Word Icon when using the FileDialog in VBA?

Reason being is that I am using the Dialog to select files another than a Word Document (or Excel when using Excel VBA).

See image below for visual of the Icon.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FileDialog doesn't allow you to do this.  However you can use the [Common File Dialog](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161286) instead.  This involves a bit more work, and a call to the [Win API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/172wfck9.aspx).

First you will need to declare the API GetOpenFileName.

```
Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long
```

Then you will need to declare the [OPENFILENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.  This allows you to configure the dialog.

```
   Private Type OPENFILENAME
     lStructSize As Long
     hwndOwner As Long
     hInstance As Long
     lpstrFilter As String
     lpstrCustomFilter As String
     nMaxCustFilter As Long
     nFilterIndex As Long
     lpstrFile As String
     nMaxFile As Long
     lpstrFileTitle As String
     nMaxFileTitle As Long
     lpstrInitialDir As String
     lpstrTitle As String
     flags As Long
     nFileOffset As Integer
     nFileExtension As Integer
     lpstrDefExt As String
     lCustData As Long
     lpfnHook As Long
     lpTemplateName As String
   End Type
```

Using these two objects you can call the common dialog like this:

```
Private Sub Example()
    Dim OpenFile As OPENFILENAME
    Dim lReturn As Long
    Dim sFilter As String

    'Configure the dialog.
    OpenFile.lStructSize = Len(OpenFile)
    sFilter = "Batch Files (*.bat)" & Chr(0) & "*.BAT" & Chr(0)
    OpenFile.lpstrFilter = sFilter
    OpenFile.nFilterIndex = 1
    OpenFile.lpstrFile = String(257, 0)
    OpenFile.nMaxFile = Len(OpenFile.lpstrFile) - 1
    OpenFile.lpstrFileTitle = OpenFile.lpstrFile
    OpenFile.nMaxFileTitle = OpenFile.nMaxFile
    OpenFile.lpstrInitialDir = "C:\"
    OpenFile.lpstrTitle = "Use the Comdlg API not the OCX"
    OpenFile.flags = 0

    ' Call the dialog.
    lReturn = GetOpenFileName(OpenFile)

    ' Inspect the result.
    If lReturn = 0 Then
       MsgBox "The User pressed the Cancel Button"
    Else
       MsgBox "The user Chose " & Trim(OpenFile.lpstrFile)
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** In my original answer I didn't explain how to add an icon to the dialog.  This is done by setting the HwndOwner property of the OpenFileName structure.  The Dialog will pickup the icon of the passed [windows handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)) (hwnd).

Comment: How would I go about adding a specific icon before the Title?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an explanation.  You might also want to read this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SetIcon.aspx.  It details how to change the icon of a running app, which would then be used by the Common File Dialog.

Comment: Thanks, I used the script in the **cpearson** link to find the hwndOwner number for my desired App and I then assigned it with the `OpenFile.hwndOwner`

Comment: Correction. Once I use the script link to assign my desired icon to Excel, I can then use that assigned number for my OpenFile.hwndOwner, but I can seem to get it to work without assigning it to Excel first.